# Initializing Variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm working on a project that involves using Excel VBA. Unfortunately, I'm new to VBA and I think I ended up confusing myself while coding. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w2fv716b65x4fp/Beer.xlsm?dl=0)'s the file I'm working with.

When I attempted to test the form out, it pops out a message box saying

`Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range`

And when I click "Debug", it highlighted the line

`If wantsBYO = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x + 1, 8) Or wantsBYO = "Unsure" Then`

I'm guessing this is because I did something wrong with the variable initialization, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Check the value of *x* when it gets to the line.

Comment: @jcbermu - There are 52 lines. I only want lines 2 - 52 and I have the index running from 1 to 51, so I made it x+1 instead of x. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have renamed all worksheets in your workbook to something else than "Sheet2", so

```
Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

Will result in an error.  Change "Sheet2" to whatever worksheet-name you require in your code and it should not give this error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary possible reasons for failure:

- A worksheet with the name "Sheet2" does not exist
- `x < 0` or `x > 1,048,575` (or 65,535 if you're working with an older format file)

Most likely, the issue is with your sheet name as @CoRrRan already mentioned. In general, I try to use the CodeName of worksheets instead of their Name. The CodeName is what shows up in the Project Viewer in VBA Editor (the tree structure showing all the objects in the project that, by default, is docked on the left side of the screen). The CodeName is not likely to be changed by the typical user and, therefore, is more robust. In fact, the worksheet is most likely still named Sheet2 as a CodeName. In that instance, you would change the line to:

```
If wantsBYO = Sheet2.Cells(x + 1, 8) Or wantsBYO = "Unsure" The
```